# How to run NTILE sql function when its parameter is part of the record

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have the following table, called `Bucket`:

```
bucketId bucketSpace  totalItemsOnBuckets
1        1            21
1        2            21
1        3            21
1        4            21
2        1            9 
2        2            9 
2        3            9
```

I'm trying to produce the following output using `NTILE`

```
bucketId bucketSpace  bucketSpaceItems totalItemsOnBuckets
1        1            5                21
1        2            5                21
1        3            5                21
1        4            6                21
2        1            3                9 
2        2            3                9 
2        3            3                9
```

As you can see, the `NTILE` value, is a column within the row.

I have tried several options

```
select 
    b.*,
    NTILE(b.totalItemsOnBuckets) OVER(PARTITION BY bucketId order by bucketId, bucketSpace) AS bucketSpaceItems 
from 
    Bucket b
```

but all of them gives me the error:

> The reference to column "columnName" is not allowed in an argument to the NTILE function. Only references to columns at an outer scope or standalone expressions and subqueries are allowed here.

Using the error as a hint, I have tried subqueries, cross join, but all of them return the same error.

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/6decd/2

Answer (score 2):

`NTILE()` only allows constants (for some definition of "constant") for the number of tiles.  But you can easily calculate it with other window functions:

```
select ceiling(row_number() over (partition by bucketid order by bucketSpace) * totalItemsOnBuckets * 1.0 /
               count(*) over (partition by bucketid)
              ) as tile
```

Comment: Not *strictly* true, as mentioned by the error message you can use an outer scope's value if you `cross apply` this query into it. Or if you use a non-correlated subquery. Obviously neither of these is really relevant here unless you self-join

Comment: Gordon Linoff, You answer is close but it dons't split the results like NTILE(). I was looking for a bucketSpaceItems = 5, 5, 5, 6, but your answer returns bucketSpaceItems = 6, 11, 16, 21

Comment: @roncansan . . . Then I'm not sure you want `ntile()` in the first place.

Comment: Gordon Linoff, agree with you, I misunderstood ntile. still thanks

Answer (score 1):

I end up using, Gordon Linoff, with some modifications.

```
;with count_per_bucket as
(
select 
    b.*,
    ceiling(row_number() over (partition by bucketid order by bucketSpace) * totalItemsOnBuckets * 1.0 / count(*) over (partition by bucketid)) as cumulativeCount
from 
    #bucket b
),

count_per_bucket_analisys as
(
    select 
        *, 
        lead(cumulativeCount,1,0) over (partition by bucketid order by bucketSpace) as nextCumulativeCount,
        lag(cumulativeCount,1,0) over (partition by bucketid order by bucketSpace) as previousCumulativeCount
    from 
        count_per_bucket
)

select 
    *,
    ItemsPerBucket =  
      CASE 
         WHEN previousCumulativeCount = 0 THEN cumulativeCount   
         WHEN nextCumulativeCount = 0 THEN cumulativeCount - previousCumulativeCount 
         ELSE nextCumulativeCount - cumulativeCount
      END  
from count_per_bucket_analisys
```

Comment: Finally, I think the title of the issue should be change since the final solution didn't use NTILE